# Include data in WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have to create a new WordPress theme, the client gave me the PSD files of the contents. There are many pages and each pages has a unique structure. I need to provide a WordPress theme to the client (only the theme folder), but it needs to fill the contents into the theme (not from the wp admin panel).

So when the client installs the theme on his server, he needs to get the contents in the site as are in the PSD file.

Is there any method to fill the content along with the theme so that he would be able to edit it later?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The content has to be in the database, do you want to hardcode in your pages instead???

Answer (score 0):

[Wordpress has a built-in template engine.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Answer (score 0):

You are dreadfully mistaking themes/templates with data.

In wordpress, your template is supposed to be able to output the BLOG data that the user wants to enter. If you have lots of data to show, custom one, for example, events, cars, people, look for a pluggin that allows you to manage and show this information.

If you absolutely want to show data from the template, create tons of templates representing each pages, and when your client wants to show that page, he creates a PAGE in wordpress and selects the right template that shows the data hardcoded...

Comment: Note that i do NOT recommend hardcoding data into a template, this is NOT how wordpress was designed to work... Youre better off making a static HTML site intead :S

Comment: What did i get wrong? It's nice of you to tell me something is wrong, but what?

Comment: He is asking how to add data dynamically to WordRress when his theme gets activated I think.

Comment: k, maybe you're right, maybe you're not, i think he wants to make a theme with hardcoded data of some sorts... Which, you won't disagree with me, is BAD practice...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_insert_post()` to insert custom content on theme activation. All will happen on the backside and the client will be happy.

Comment: Here is more information about wp_insert_post() https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Answer (score 0):

you have to creat different pages file eg. page1.php,page2.php.....

```
 <?php
/*
Template Name: tamplage name eg page1
*/
?>
```

add above code to each file i mean page1.php,page2.php...

Now in WordPress admin you creat a page and select tamplete for each pages.....  default tamplate is use for page.php